# Born and Wolf (7th ed) Scattering theory (Ch. 13 Eqn. 1)

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, scattering

In "Principles of Optics" 7th ed. by Born and Wolf, Ch. 13 Eqn. 1 describes the electric field for a monochromatic field in a nonmagnetic medium below. However, I don't understand where the $\mu_0$ factor went in the second term. Do they set $\mu_0 = 1$? If so, this doesn't make sense to me. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: it is in the relationship between $k$ and $\omega$, $c^2\mu_0\epsilon_0=1$ and $\epsilon$ is dimensionless.